# Can I preload games on Origin?

Tags: origin

I know games can be preloaded on steam (downloaded before the day of release so you can play it as soon as it unlocks) but does anyone know if EA's new client Origin will offer the same feature?

I'm hoping to preload before the release of Battlefield 3 on Friday (UK) - am I going to have to use the probably heavily overloaded servers on the day of release?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

I got this email on the 21st:

Dear XXXXX:
Thank you for ordering on Origin Store. The product that you preordered is now available for preload. Click the link below to preload your product.

Order Number: XXXX
Product ID: XXXXX
Product Name: Battlefield 3™ Limited Edition 
Release Date: October 24, 2011

To download your game just visit the "My Games" section of the Origin application. You will be sent an email on the release date when your game is ready to play.

Don't have Origin? Visit http://www.origin.com/download to download and install the Origin application. Once installed, click the sign-in tab and log in with the Origin Account you used for your purchase at the Origin Store to access your available games.

Please note: This email message was sent from a notification-only address that cannot accept incoming email. Please visit help.origin.com/ to submit any further questions.

Answer (score 4):

From [EA Support](http://ea.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/5881/session/L3RpbWUvMTMxOTQ0NDQ1Ny9zaWQvVGRoWHdsSGs=):

> ****MISSION BRIEFING:****
>
> **In order to play Battlefield 3 on PC, you’ll need to have the latest
>   version of Origin installed on your
>   computer, and an Origin account. Download it now and get into the
>   battle faster.**
>
> **Q: I’ve purchased Battlefield 3 PC download through Origin or other distributor and pre-loaded it. When will I be able to play?**
>
> A: Battlefield 3 PC digital pre-loads, as well as the actual packaged
>   product, will become available to play at the following times,
>   depending on your country location.
>
> Friday, October 28th, 12:01am British Summer Time (GMT +1) Bangladesh,
>   Bhutan, India, Ireland, Italy, Nepal, Pakistan, Portugal, South
>   Africa, United Kingdom

So, yes, it would seem that BF3 is indeed preloaded.